# Is there any nice way of identifying which model of Peerless Bathroom Faucet I have?

Tags: faucet

I have a 2 handle bathroom faucet which says Peerless on the underside.  It came with the house when I bought it and I don't have the packaging or manual for it.  I am trying to identify the correct stem unit assembly for it to stop a small drip and I know how you have to get the right part for the right faucet or it will not fit.  I tried the website for Peerless and the 3 candidates I came up with for replacement part are (although none look like the replacement part):

1. RP70201 - Got a pack, doesn't fit
2. RP71444 - Doesn't match the look of the old part, but it is a replacement for many models.  Could try that next
3. RP41701 - Doesn't match the look of the old part, but readily available

So is there anywhere/any way I can tell for sure.  I could post a picture of  my faucet if helpful.  I could even uninstall my old cartridge and post a picture of that if it helps.

Comment: The brand is Peerless, perhaps you need the model...

Comment: @SolarMike Exactly, but I don't know the model, so I am stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the cartridge is out, take it to a *plumbing supply house* not your local big-box home improvement center.

Odds are very good that they'll either

- know off the top of their heads,
- be able to find a part number that you're missing,
- or just simply walk to the back and open 12 boxes looking for one that matches and sell you that one.

One additional tip: Call ahead. Some places will only sell wholesale, i.e. to commercial plumbers. Others will sell retail, i.e. to you.

Answer (score 2):

Although @FreeMan gives sound advice, I really don't have anybody to go to, especially in the current half-closed world.  So I bought RP41701, and although the base of the cartridge looked slightly different than the old part, it actually did fit and lo and behold I have hot water without any drip.  Problem solved.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed, and thanks for reporting back in to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

On the Peerless customer support page, click [Contact Us](https://www.peerlessfaucet.com/customer-support/contact-us) to get to a web form to request help.

There you can upload a photo of the faucet so they can identify the faucet model and its parts.

Comment: Ok, I gave it a try. I will let you know if they can identify it.

Comment: Peerless never returned my email.  Although they did send me a survey link wanting to know how their service was.

Comment: Bummer. In contrast, BrassCraft answered which parts to get before I opened a shut-off valve and that I should do all the valves in the house. They were right on both counts.